# Is it possible to disable ACPI Suspend in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, windows-registry, suspend, acpi

Is it possible to disable ACPI Suspend in Windows XP?

I don't mean the "Control Panel, Power Settings,..., choose never to sleep, actions on button, choose 'ask me', actions on close lid, choose 'no action', etc..." solution. [1]

I mean **totally disable the suspend functionality**, the same way I can totally disable Hibernation by uncheking a box inside a tab in Power Settings that is made for this purpose.

*[1] That takes a long time to do and somehow stops on several other annoyances, such as this setting not being properly propagated to each user account.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this should achieve what you're after.

Open up `regedit` and navigate to the following location:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\ACPI\Parameters
```

Create a new `DWORD` value named **Attributes**, set it's data to hexadecimal and input the value `70`.

Exit `regedit` and reboot.

Comment: Thanks. What does the 70 mean? Is it a binary expansion of a bunch of settings like in linux file permissions?

Comment: @user - I've no idea. *Possibly*. I came accross this answer [in](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/81483-35-stop-computer-standby) [several](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2341076,00.asp) [places](http://www.annoyances.org/exec/forum/winme/t1024908651) though, so it would appear to be a good bet.

Comment: Indeed it is. I googled the registry you mention and found a lot of links as well.

7=111 in binary which disables all S1, S2 and S3 suspend modes.

http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/74843-disable-standby-tweak/
http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/81483-45-stop-computer-standby
http://blog.tiensivu.com/aaron/archives/698-Enable-better-performance-under-XP-SP2-if-you-have-a-lot-of-ACPI-devices-sharing-the-ACPI-interrupt!.html
http://www.exoid.com/?page_id=47
http://www.infdump.com/inffiles/B/BIOSINFO.INF

Comment: @user39559 Good bit of reseach that, and good intuition on it being a bit field.

Comment: Well, 3, 7, 15 and 63 are suspicious numbers.

Answer (score 0):

To disable ACPI, do the following:

1. In Device Manager, right-click on
   "Advanced Configuration and Power
   Interface (ACPI) PC" under the
   "Computer" header and select "Update
   Driver".
2. Select "Install from a list or
   specific location (advanced)" and
   click Next.
3. Select "Don't Search. I will choose
   the driver to install" and click
   Next.
4. Select "Standard PC" and click Next.
5. Click Next and OK to the end.

I suggest, just in case, to create a system restore point before doing the above, and also to note down the existing driver.

If this is not enough, you might consider turning off ACPI in the BIOS. However, be warned that changing this BIOS parameter might require the re-installation of XP.

Comment: Wouldn't it ruin other controls, like fan control, screen luminosity, or even the Power Off functionality?

Comment: @user39559: It might entail some lose of functionality, but that depends on the computer model. Which is why I suggested the system restore point as a way back.